# Flutter firebase setData() function assigns null value to a field before completion of an async function

Tags: firebase, flutter, asynchronous, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to upload an avatar for a user to firestore storage and return the image url to save it against users avatarUrl property on the user instance. I am able to upload the image to firestore successfully. the issue comes with the receiving back of the url. The async function delays and hence the preceding user instanciation function proceeds with a null value for the avatarUrl property.

**Here is the function initiation**

```
                    if(_formKey.currentState.validate()){
                      setState(() {
                        loading=true;
                      });
                      await uploadFile();
                      print('Print before async function complete...');
                      print(_avatarUrl);
                      dynamic result=  await SellerDatabaseService(uid:user.uid).sellerProfileSetup(
                        shopName: shopName,
                        phone: phone,
                        bio: bio,
                        location: location,
                        avatarUrl: _avatarUrl,
                        rating: 0,
                        sales: 0,
                        credit: 0,
                        posts: 0,
                        joinedDate:DateTime.now(),
                        //todo remove null from profile image
                      );
                      if(result==null){
                        setState(() {
                          loading=false;
                          error='Please supply correct details';
                        });
                      }
                    }
                  },
```

***Here is the upload function***

```
 String _avatarUrl;
  Future uploadFile() async {
    StorageReference storageReference = FirebaseStorage.instance
        .ref()
        .child('avatars/${_image.path}');
    StorageUploadTask uploadTask = storageReference.putFile(_image);
    await uploadTask.onComplete;
    print('File Uploaded');
    storageReference.getDownloadURL().then((fileURL) {
      setState(() {
        _avatarUrl = fileURL;
        print('Print after async function completes...');
        print(_avatarUrl);

      });
    });
  }
```

***This is the output***

```
I/flutter ( 7332): Print before async function complete...
I/flutter ( 7332): null
I/flutter ( 7332): Print after async function completes...
I/flutter ( 7332): https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/sakahapa-77a09.appspot.com/o/avatars%2Fdata%2Fuser%2F0%2Fcom.sakahapa.sakaHapa%2Fcache%2Fimage_picker246664303.jpg?alt=media&token=5868d6a5-b1e3-4aa2-8e64-72dc6e9b0a0f
```

As seen there the url returns later after the `SellerDatabaseService(uid:user.uid).sellerProfileSetup()`
function has run. So i get a null value on the avatarUrl property. How do i prevent this?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this:

```
    storageReference.getDownloadURL().then((fileURL) {
      setState(() {
        _avatarUrl = fileURL;
        print('Print after async function completes...');
        print(_avatarUrl);

      });
    });
```

into this:

```
    var fileURL = await storageReference.getDownloadURL();
      setState(() {
        _avatarUrl = fileURL;
        print('Print after async function completes...');
        print(_avatarUrl);

      });
    });
```

Use `await` instead of `then()`. Currently you are entering the method `uploadFile()`, but since `getDownloadURL()` is asynchronous then the `print()` method is getting executed even before getting the url.